# using .aspx page as Jquery Cluetip?

Tags: wcf, jquery-ui, jquery, popup, mouseenter

I am using an .aspx page as cluetip bound to an anchor tag. I need to pass a parameter from anchor to this page and then call a WCF service to populate my template with returned JSON. I tried putting body onload function but that doesnt seems to work.

Thanks
Koby.

Answer (score 0):

**response to comment**

You want to use the `.mouseenter()` event.  This new event in 1.4 is better than .blur() which is what you will see in most examples (and probably why you can find it, a search of `blur jquery popup` should give you lots of examples).  But mouseenter is better in the lastest jQuery

Docs: (very nice example code at the bottom of the page.)

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

**old version**

just add the function to the onclick handler.  You can do this in jquery with something like this

```
$(selector).click(function () {
   code to do stuff (call wcf and populate)
   you can use $(this) to see what was clicked on. ("passed" as you put it)
 });
```

see fab new jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Hi Hogan, Thanks for the reply, What I am trying to do here is to show my Jquery cluetip on mouseover event of image and I want my aspx page(clue tip now) to get dynamically populated with returned JSON. I tried putting WCF call in onload event but that doesnt seems to fire.